# Bundle identifier cannot be changed from previous version

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an error when trying to submit the first update for my app to iTunes Connect.

When going through the Distribute operation to "Submit to the iOS App Store" I pick the new app version I have created in iTunes Connect, and the only Code Signing Identity available.  XCode then tells me that

> "This bundle is invalid.  The bundle identifier cannot be changed from
>   the previous version.  If you want to change your bundle identifier,
>   you will need to create a new application in iTunes Connect."

However, the iTunes Connect page for my app tells me that the Bundle ID is

```
com.mycompany.myapp
```

And in the XCode Targets Summary the Bundle Identifier is set to

```
com.mycompany.myapp
```

I have literally copied the text from the web page and pasted it into XCode to be sure.

The the Version and Build numbers are 0.1 higher than the version already in iTunes.

I have tried:

- googling
- deleting the Derived Data directory in Organizer
- changing the bundle ID, archiving then changing it back again
- even turning it on and off again

All to no avail.  There appears to be no google result for "The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version" though quite a few that include the word "minor" but unfortunately they do not help.

Comment: If you go into iTunes Connect, click on the app, what does it say for the Bundle Identifier.

Comment: It tells me it's exactly what I've got in XCode.  I've even copied it from iTunes into XCode to make sure

Comment: Check the bundle for the distribution certificate. I've seen this before myself, but I can't remember exactly how I fixed it. I think it had to do with the distro profile.

Comment: Distribution certificate - is that the same as the Provisioning Profile?  My provisioning profile has an App Identifier of "aabbcc.com.mycompany.myapp", so the same as the Bundle ID but with an 10 digit prefix.

Comment: Looks like there is just one way to solve that. Contact Apple.

Comment: Did you change the Product Name? I used to have a same problem after changing the product name

Comment: The mistake I have made is I do not choose right app in "Choose an application record ..." dialog. By default, it chooses another app of mine.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error until I went to iTunesConnect and pressed "Ready for Upload" for the new version, at which point the status changes to "Waiting For Upload". There was never anything wrong with the bundle identifier, so the message "bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version" is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar - where I mess up the build version, (updating the app) so added a build version of 1.0.1, and then a Project  then build in the simulator. Next I re-uploaded to itunes - via the Archive root.  NB: If this is the first time you have sent it to iTunes - they it is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Got it this morning. Solved it by going to iTunes. The was noted that the app was already in "Ready for review". Strangely enough. Solved this by:

- Click on the app "View Details" -> "Binary Details" -> "Reject Binary".
- After this I immediately set the status to "Ready for Binary Upload"
- Distributed the app via Xcode.