# iPhone app update doesn't validate because of bundle id

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

We have not been able to publish our first update to our iPhone app on the app store.
The validate step after build always fails with:

"This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the previous version. If you want to change your bundle identifier you will need to create a new application in itunes connect."

We have only one Apple account with only one app. We have not changed the bundle id in the plist file ever since we released earlier in the summer (it was different before we released though). it is "com.company.product" (with our real company name and real product name all in lowercase). We only increased the version number from 1.0 to 1.10 (after seeing articles here with problems going to 1.1)

The iTunes connect is expecting 1.10 and the same bundle id. Spent 2 days Googling but can't find anything useful and tried different versions and bundle ids etc but nothing was good. 
Please help!

(I have also sent an itunes connect question on this to Apple but no response so far)

Comment: What does iTunesConnect tell you the bundleID is? And what is it like in your project?

Comment: Also, check: [Bundle identifier cannot be changed from previous version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371263/bundle-identifier-cannot-be-changed-from-previous-version)

Comment: Try to analyze: open the IPA (rename to .zip and doubleclick) or the .app File (right click, show contents). Open the Info.plist file in Textmate (http://macromates.com) chose Bundle->Property List->Convert Binary to XML. Check the bundle ID.... you might then find the difference!

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies: 1 - itunesConnect says exactly the same as the plist. 2 - The other article didn't help sadly. 3 - I always edit the plist in xml but good idea I will try to see if the zipped up build has a for some reason any difference.

Comment: by the way my plist is called "product-Info.plist" - that should be fine as putting a wrong version makes it complain about version numbers so it does pick up from there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error before, I'm not sure however if you have done the same thing I did:

In versions 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 of my app, it only supported iPhone. I then got an iPad of my own for testing. In version 1.3 of my app, I updated it to support iPhone and iPad. It wouldn't upload, giving me this error. Turns out if you want a universal app, it has to be universal from the start, you cant decide in version 1.4 or whatever that you want to add iPad compatibility.